# Where can I check a T-SQL function is available in a specific version?

Tags: t-sql

Where can I find a list to make sure the functions I am using are available in older versions of Microsoft SQL Server?

We recently ran into issues with someone using CONCAT which won't work on some of our older servers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of supported versions is generally documented in the docs for each individual function. For example, [the docs for CONCAT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) show "SQL Server (all supported versions)" in the "Applies to" section. The same section will tell you if the article applies to other flavors of SQL Server, such as Azure SQL Database.  Similarly on [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), the docs show it is supported in "SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later"

Also note that as of today, "all supported versions" means SQL Server 2012+. Microsoft does not maintain docs for how the product functioned in out-of-support versions, so information on what works in older versions would need to come from elsewhere.

Additionally, the supported version may be tied to [the database compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15) as well. In this case, assume that the databases compatibility must be at the supported version, in addition to the database engine version.

I am not aware of a centralized matrix that shows the crosstab of functions & supported versions, so doing a lookup on each individual function's page will be your best bet for finding the necessary info.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/end-of-support/sql-server-end-of-life-overview?view=sql-server-ver15 if I scroll way down there is a table with Lifecycle dates.

Comment: End of support dates are documented, yes. However, articles on docs.microsft.com can't be depended upon to accurately tell you whether any given feature was included in older versions.